# When an expression has double brackets in it ($[[x]]$), what type of expression is this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I am curious to know what type but I know that one is greatest integer parent function.  There is another one that explains it and I want to know what another function represents that?

Answer (score 1):

Double square brackets $[\![a, b]\!]$ are used also to mean the interval of all integers between a and b included.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that your answer is here : https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090710203054AA3mCg9
Here, it is said that the double brackets ($[[x]]$) mean rounding off, to be frank.